# got The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am a newbie to Spring mvc and trying to learn it.I just want to print a message "Hi Welcome to Spring MVC" but i am getting this error --->

HTTP Status 404

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Any help will be appreciated.

I am using tomcat 9.0 version server

**WEB*

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Hello-servlet**

```
 <beans schema

<context:component-scan base-package="com.helloworld" />

<bean class 
="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloController**

```
    package com.helloworld;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView printHello()
{
   return new ModelAndView("hello","Hellomsg", "Hi Welcome to Spring 
MVC");  

}

}
```

I expect the output ---
Hi Welcome to Spring MVC

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to hit?

Comment: Did you inspect your code on the browser? can you include the screen shot of the browser inspection that shows the HTTP calls and responses

Comment: The problem is resolved now..There was some version mismatch in spring..Thanks for the response  @elolelo

Answer (score 0):

try compiling javac --release yourfilename.java
in compiler with the path of the file provided

Comment: You guess? This should be a comment but obviously you don't have the privilege to post comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).